# Auto gain control with Basler camera

Tags: c#, camera

I drive Basler camera with a C# program and I would like to perform an automatic gain control for gain is automatically adjusted according to the brightness. I need your help because at first glance, I did not realize how well visualized it.

A library is supplied with the camera and thanks to her I control the camera. The user has the opportunity to capture a photo, video capture and stop video capture. It can also control the gain manually. I wish now program the automatic gain, that is to say, the gain is automatically adjusted depending on the intensity of the captured image. Users just activate this setting and the gain setting would automatically.

```
Camera camera = new Camera();       
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.GainSelector].SetValue(PLUsbCamera.GainSelector.DigitalAll);
    camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.AutoGainLowerLimit].SetValue(0.0); 
    camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.AutoGainUpperLimit].SetToMaximum(); 
    camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.AutoTargetBrightness].SetValue(0.50196); 
    camera.Parameters[PLUsbCamera.GainAuto].SetValue(PLUsbCamera.GainAuto.Continuous);
}
```

I have an exception when I run my program. This exception said " Parameter in path CameraDevice can only be accessed when the camera is open. "

I don't know how to correct this error because my camera is already open as I can make a capture.

Comment: Do you really have the line `Camera camera = new Camera()` in your code? Or have you just not included the code where this camera is opened?

Comment: Yes I do. I have this line in my code.

Comment: OK - then is this camera initialised and "opened"? If not then that would explain your error.

Comment: When I run my Form, I can capture photo and video so the camera is opened.

Comment: But is the capture using that Camera object or a different one?

Comment: Maybe an other one. At the beginning of my code, I declare two variables : 
private ImageProvider m_imageProvider = new ImageProvider(); /* Create one image provider. */
        private Bitmap m_bitmap = null; /* The bitmap is used for displaying the image. */